# Cannot get result post id after sharing photo to Facebook by ios app (Swift and FBSDK4.0.1)

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, photo, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm writing an iOS app to do photo sharing.

Using technology Swift and FBSDK 4.0.1

I found that photo sharing by FBSDKShare**Photo**Content()
CANNOT get back any post id from result object in `FBSDKSharingDelegate` inside method `didCompleteWithResults`.

Result object contains empty row:

```
[:]
```

However, URL sharing by FBSDKShare**Link**Content()
can get back post id from the result object.
something like that:

```
[postId: 10000844250000_146108069750000]
```

Part of my core code:

1. Image Picker Controller (`UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`, `UINavigationControllerDelegate`)

   ```
   func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

   var theImage:UIImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
   uploadImage.image = theImage
   self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
   }
   ```

2. After choosing photo,  click custom share button

   ```
    @IBAction func postButtonClick(sender: AnyObject) {

      let photoContent = FBSDKSharePhotoContent()

      let photo : FBSDKSharePhoto = FBSDKSharePhoto()
      photo.image = uploadImage.image
      photo.userGenerated = true

      photoContent.photos = [photo]

      FBSDKShareDialog.showFromViewController(self, withContent: photoContent, delegate:self)
   }
   ```
3. Facebook `FBSDKSharingDelegate`

   ```
    func sharer(sharer: FBSDKSharing!, didCompleteWithResults results: [NSObject: AnyObject])
    {
       println("sharer didCompleteWithResults, results.count\(results.count)")
       println(results)
       // still cannot get post id from photo upload
    }

    func sharer(sharer: FBSDKSharing!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {

       println("sharer NSError")
       println(error.description)

    }

    func sharerDidCancel(sharer: FBSDKSharing!) {

       println("sharerDidCancel")

    }
   ```

I will appreciate your help.

Comment: Are both photo and link shares done by the same user? Normally you'll only get the postId if the user has granted your app publish_actions permissions, even if you use the native share dialog.

Comment: Hi Ming Li, yes both shares done by same user with publish_actions permission. So it is strange.

Comment: if you have granted  publish_permissions and are not receiving the ID, you should probably file a bug here : https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Hi lamdadj22, ok thanks =). I reported here https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/665877423517215/

Comment: @LeoKaHoLee, Found anything?

Answer (score 0):

```
    let photo = FBSDKSharePhoto()
    photo.image = chosenImage
    photo.isUserGenerated = false
    let photoContent = FBSDKSharePhotoContent()
    photoContent.photos = [photo]
    let shareApiInstance = FBSDKShareAPI()
    shareApiInstance.message = "customized facebook content"
    shareApiInstance.shareContent = photoContent
    shareApiInstance.delegate = self
    shareApiInstance.share()
```

// Delegate Methods

func sharer(_ sharer: FBSDKSharing!, didCompleteWithResults results: [AnyHashable : Any]!) {
        print("delegates called")

```
    let resultsInfo = results as! [String : Any]
    print(resultsInfo["postId"] as! String)
}

func sharer(_ sharer: FBSDKSharing!, didFailWithError error: Error!) {
    print("sharer NSError")
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}

func sharerDidCancel(_ sharer: FBSDKSharing!) {
    print("sharerDidCancel")
}
```

with the above workaround you can access postId.

Comment: if you have publish_actions permissions then only it will be possible.

Comment: Consider explaining your code before posting your solution

Comment: With the help of FBSDKShareAPI() you can get the post id.